# Calling Web Method in Web Service

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, web-services

Basically I am trying to consume web service methods in JavaScript class in ASP.NET. So here is the methods in my web service:

```
[WebMethod]
    public DataSet GetFireStation()
    {
        SqlConnection sqlConnection1 = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
        string select = "select * from dbo.FireStation ";
        sqlConnection1.Open();
        // Create an Adapter
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(select, sqlConnection1);
        // Create a New DataSet
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        // Fill The DataSet With the Contents of the Stock Table
        da.Fill(ds, "FireStation");
        sqlConnection1.Close();
        // Now Return ds which is a DataSet
        return (ds);
    }
```

Then here is my HTML code which call the function in JavaScript class:

```
 case "Accident":
            if (type == 'Accident') {
                symbol = new esri.symbol.PictureMarkerSymbol('img/Accident.gif', 25, 20);
                htmlStr = htmlStr + "<input type='button' id='btnHosPoint' class='infoTempButton infoTempOrange' title='To Hospital' value='' onclick='getSafetyCoordXY(" + $(this).find("actualX").text() + ", " + $(this).find("actualY").text() + ", " + '\"' + type + '\"' + ");connectNearestRoute(" + $(this).find("actualX").text() + ", " + $(this).find("actualY").text() + ");' />"
                                    + "<input type='button' id='btnClinicPoint' class='infoTempButton infoTempOrange' title='To Clinic' value='Clinic' onclick='connectNearestClinic(" + $(this).find("actualX").text() + ", " + $(this).find("actualY").text() + ");' />"
                                    + "<input type='button' id='btnFirePoint' class='infoTempButton infoTempOrange' title='Nearest Fire Station' value='FS' onclick='ConnectNearsetFireStation(" + $(this).find("actualX").text() + ", " + $(this).find("actualY").text() + ");' />"
                                    + "<input type='button' id='btnPolicePoint' class='infoTempButton infoTempOrange' title='Nearest Police Station' value='Police' onclick='ConnectNearsetPolice(" + $(this).find("actualX").text() + ", " + $(this).find("actualY").text() + ");' />";
                var point = new esri.geometry.Point({ "x": $(this).find("actualX").text(), "y": $(this).find("actualY").text(), "spatialReference": { "wkid": 3414 } });
                var graphic = new esri.Graphic(point, symbol);
                map.graphics.add(graphic);

                var infoTemplate = new esri.InfoTemplate();
                infoTemplate.setTitle("<img src='img/Accident.gif' style='width:25px; height:25px;'/>&nbsp;&nbsp; " + type);
                infoTemplate.setContent("Information: " + incidentMessage + "</br>" + "</br>" + htmlStr);

                graphic.setSymbol(symbol);
                graphic.setInfoTemplate(infoTemplate);
                incidentLocation.push(graphic);
                htmlStr = "";
            }
            break;
```

And here is my function in JavaScript class which retrieve data from database which will pass thru the web service method:

**EDIT**

```
function ConnectNearsetFireStation(x, y) {

    map.infoWindow.hide();
    //map.infoWindow.resize(350, 120);

    var Fire = [];
    var FireStationPointGraphic = [];

    $.ajax({
        'type'          : 'GET',
        'url'           : 'http://localhost/SgDataService.asmx' + 'GetFireStation',
    'success'       : function(results){
    $.each(GetFireStation(), function () {
        var name = $(this).find("ID").text();

        firestation = $(this).find("Name").text();
        address = $(this).find("Address").text();
        postal = $(this).find("PostalCode").text();
        coordX = $(this).find("X").text();
        coordY = $(this).find("Y").text();

        // Compute Distance
        var IncidentPoint = new esri.geometry.Point({ "x": x, "y": y, "spatialReference": { "wkid": 3414 } });
        var FireStationPoint = new esri.geometry.Point({ "x": coordX, "y": coordY, "spatialReference": { "wkid": 3414 } });
        var distance = esri.geometry.getLength(IncidentPoint, FireStationPoint);

        Fire.push(distance);

        var point = new esri.geometry.Point({ "x": coordX, "y": coordY, "spatialReference": { "wkid": 3414 } });
        var symbol = new esri.symbol.PictureMarkerSymbol('/SAFETY_AT_SG/Images/Features/FireStation.gif', 25, 25);
        var PointGraphic = new esri.Graphic(point, symbol);

        var infoTemplate = new esri.InfoTemplate();

        infoTemplate.setTitle("<img src='/SAFETY_AT_SG/Images/Features/PoliceStation.png' style='width:25px; height:25px;'/>&nbsp;&nbsp; " + firestation);
        infoTemplate.setContent("<b>FireStation: </b>" + firestation + "<br/>"
                + "<b>Address: </b>" + address + "<br/>"
                + "<b>PostalCode: </b>" + postal + "<br/>"
                );
        PointGraphic.setSymbol(symbol);
        PointGraphic.setInfoTemplate(infoTemplate);

        //Store PoliceStation To Array
        FireStationPointGraphic.push(PointGraphic);

        //OneMap.map.graphics.add(PointGraphic)
    }
    );
    }
    });

    var minDist = Math.min.apply(null, Fire); //Get Smallest Distance

    for (var i = 0; i < Fire.length; i++) {
        if (minDist == Fire[i]) {
            var myX = FireStationPointGraphic[i].geometry.x;
            var myY = FireStationPointGraphic[i].geometry.y;

            OneMap.map.graphics.add(FireStationPointGraphic[i]);
            RouteU(x + ',' + y + ";" + myX + ',' + myY);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

However, when I try to call the GetFireStation() in conenctNearestFireStation(), it told me an error message which is GetFireStation is not defined. I wonder why is it so. Do I need to add any reference to web service if my JavaScript class is calling the methods inside?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: JavaScript is executed on the client. Your web method is available on the server. You need to make an `ajax` call to execute the webmethod and return the results to the client

Comment: uhh... JavaScript doesn't have classes.  And your "HTML Code" looks like C#.  What?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the code should end up something like this

```
function ConnectNearsetFireStation (x, y){

    var Fire = [];
    var FireStationPointGraphic = [];

    var setRoute = function (){
        var minDist = Math.min.apply(null, Fire); //Get Smallest Distance

        for (var i = 0; i < Fire.length; i++) {
            if (minDist == Fire[i]) {
                var myX = FireStationPointGraphic[i].geometry.x;
                var myY = FireStationPointGraphic[i].geometry.y;

                OneMap.map.graphics.add(FireStationPointGraphic[i]);
                RouteU(x + ',' + y + ";" + myX + ',' + myY);
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    var processFireStations = function (allFireStations){
        $.each(allFireStations, function (){
            var name = $(this).find("ID").text();

            firestation = $(this).find("Name").text();
            address = $(this).find("Address").text();
            postal = $(this).find("PostalCode").text();
            coordX = $(this).find("X").text();
            coordY = $(this).find("Y").text();

            // Compute Distance
            var IncidentPoint = new esri.geometry.Point({ "x": x, "y": y, "spatialReference": { "wkid": 3414 } });
            var FireStationPoint = new esri.geometry.Point({ "x": coordX, "y": coordY, "spatialReference": { "wkid": 3414 } });
            var distance = esri.geometry.getLength(IncidentPoint, FireStationPoint);

            Fire.push(distance);

            var point = new esri.geometry.Point({ "x": coordX, "y": coordY, "spatialReference": { "wkid": 3414 } });
            var symbol = new esri.symbol.PictureMarkerSymbol('/SAFETY_AT_SG/Images/Features/FireStation.gif', 25, 25);
            var PointGraphic = new esri.Graphic(point, symbol);

            var infoTemplate = new esri.InfoTemplate();

            infoTemplate.setTitle("<img src='/SAFETY_AT_SG/Images/Features/PoliceStation.png' style='width:25px; height:25px;'/>&nbsp;&nbsp; " + firestation);
            infoTemplate.setContent("<b>FireStation: </b>" + firestation + "<br/>"
                    + "<b>Address: </b>" + address + "<br/>"
                    + "<b>PostalCode: </b>" + postal + "<br/>"
                    );
            PointGraphic.setSymbol(symbol);
            PointGraphic.setInfoTemplate(infoTemplate);

            //Store PoliceStation To Array
            FireStationPointGraphic.push(PointGraphic);

            //OneMap.map.graphics.add(PointGraphic)
        });

        // Once the $.Each is over, map the route
        setRoute();
    };

    var getFireStations = function (){
        $.ajax({
            'type'          : 'GET',
            'url'           : 'http://localhost/SgDataService.asmx' + 'GetFireStation',
            'success'       : processFireStations
        });
    };



    map.infoWindow.hide();
    //map.infoWindow.resize(350, 120);

    getFireStations();      // start everything
}
```

Comment: It threw me an error message: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:2752' is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: This means that your html page and your webservice are not hosted in the same domain. You'll need to sort that out yourself

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript is executed on the client. Your web method is available on the server. You need to make an ajax call to execute the webmethod and return the results to the client

This means that you need to write an additional javascript function. JQuery will really help you with this as it provides some simplified, cross-browser compatible methods to make ajax calls.

```
// $ is a shortcut for jQuery
$.ajax({
    'type'          : 'GET',
    'url'           : yoururl + 'GetFireStation'
    'success'       : function(results){
                          // do stuff
                      }
}});
```

**Please note:**

> `AJAX` makes an asynchronous call, which means that you may have to
>   rethink how you've written your javascript functions so far

**Update**

Lots more info and examples on the jQuery [API page for ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Comment: What should I replace for the yoururl? My current url is http://localhost:2752/index.aspx. So I just simply replace it?

Comment: @20Cents yes, it should be the url of your `GetFireStation` webservice

Comment: @20Cents Check out the jQuery documentation for [ajax calls](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Comment: Can you help me check for the edited portion? I not sure if I am doing in the correct way